# Trimming or cutting a a part of a string in java

Tags: java, unicode, trim

I've a string, "শাকসবজি কিনুন".

How can I cut off the " কিনুন" part of this string in java? 
Having issue over here because of Unicode.

I tried this :

```
String y1 = "শাকসবজি কিনুন";
        System.out.println(y1);
        y1 = y1.replace(" কিনুন", "");
        System.out.println(y1)
```

I got this

```
à¦¶à¦¾à¦•à¦¸à¦¬à¦œà¦¿ à¦•à¦¿à¦¨à§�à¦¨
à¦¶à¦¾à¦•à¦¸à¦¬à¦œà¦¿
```

Comment: The issue appears to be that your terminal cannot display Unicode, rather than any issue with the trimming.

Comment: I'm actually running this into a list and getting out of bound exception, while debugging through, in that case also, I'm getting this sort of characters, would be great if you could suggest something.

Comment: Try this https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/

Comment: I run the code on my machine and get: 
শাকসবজি  as result so it my be a issue with displaying Unicode. I am using Java 8

Comment: I'm also using java 8

Comment: Voting to close, can not be reproduced. Is not related to the code, the code works fine. Needs more detail about the setup of the console.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal probably can't display Unicode.

Try piping your output into a file and opening it with a text editor.

If it works then there's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what parts to cut off you can use String.substring like so:

```
String y1 = "শাকসবজি কিনুন";
System.out.println(y1);
y1 = y1.substring(5)
System.out.println(y1)
```

To with this method, you can trim off a specified part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you may just need a font that will render Bengali characters. You don't state your environment, but one such font that is generally available on Windows is *Arial Unicode MS*.

Having set the font for the source code and the output to be *Arial Unicode MS*, your code works fine when I run your code in NetBeans:

[image: Bengali font]

Having an IDE makes using a specific font straightforward, but there may be additional steps needed depending on your operating system and specific requirements. For example, you may need to load a specific font and set the code page appropriately for command line output in Windows, but that is outside the scope of your question.